# How to parse xsd:schema file using openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I got layer column names using this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33674/how-to-get-column-names-of-layer-wms-using-openlayers). But I am stuck parsing it. How to parse this xml using openlayers?

```xml
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:11032/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="statesType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_FIPS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SUB_REGION" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_ABBR" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="LAND_KM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WATER_KM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PERSONS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FAMILIES" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HOUSHOLD" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FEMALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WORKERS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DRVALONE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CARPOOL" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PUBTRANS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EMPLOYED" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="UNEMPLOY" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SERVICE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MANUAL" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="P_MALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="P_FEMALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SAMP_POP" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="states" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="topp:statesType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the xsd file

```
     <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml"' +
     schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd" />' +
```

you can extract the elements

```
var res = parser.read(text);
```

Full code:

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/tests/Format/WFSDescribeFeatureType.html