# How to compose WFS GetFeature link from WMS capabilities definition?

Tags: shapefile, wms, wfs, gml

This [publication of geoinformation](http://daten.hamburg.de/daten/3810820/open-data-searchresult.html?resNumber=1&pagingResNumber=1) provides download links for `GetCapabilities` documents via WMS. The platform also runs a WFS service as can been seen [here](http://daten.hamburg.de/daten/3810820/open-data-searchresult.html?resNumber=7&pagingResNumber=7).

I wonder if it is possbile to compose a **download link** for ShapeFiles/GML or another format which can be converted ... from the given WMS information. I managed to display the street tree information in QGIS and could load details for individual features. However, this is pixel data and I would like to download **vector data** if possible.

The [second GetCapabilities document](http://geodienste-hamburg.de/HH_WMS_Fachdaten?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities) defines layers named `pflanzstandorte2011` and `pflanzstandorte_aktuell`. It would be nice if these were accessible via the platform's WFS API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI not all WMS implicitly deploy WFS.  Having said this, there are a couple of approaches to help:

1./ scan the Capabilities XML for (optional) `Layer/DataURL` elements. If they exist, `DataURL/@xlink:href` should point to a download of the data

2./ Use the WMS `DescribeLayer` operation to examine whether there are associated WFS or WCS endpoints (ref: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#operations) to the given layer

Comment: Which of the two Capabilities XML should I scan? Can you tell what the `DescribeLayer` URL is for this server? [This](http://geodienste-hamburg.de/HH_WMS_Fachdaten?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=DescribeLayer) and [this](http://gateway.hamburg.de/OGCFassade/BSU_WMS_Baumkataster.aspx?&REQUEST=DescribeLayer&SERVICE=WMS) are not valid.

Comment: Looks like this WMS does not support the `DesribeLayer` operation, then, nor has any `Layer/DataURL`.  The two approaches above are supported by the WMS specification, however appears not to be implemented by the service provider, in this particular case.