# How to set up a querystring for a MapServer layer?

Tags: mapserver, query, web-service, querystring

I am trying to query a MapServer layer via URL, but I am having trouble finding syntax examples. I want to use the indexquery mode and found this documentation http://gislars.github.io/mapserver_docs/cgi/controls.html as well as this http://mapserver.org/tutorial/example1-1.html. I am successful in returning the layer in map mode, but am not sure how to structure the indexquery string.

UPDATE: Upon further investigation it seems I need to use itemnquery mode. I have found some syntax that seems like it should work in this thread https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/4711, but I don't have access to the column names, and am not sure how to get them. Ultimately I'd like to query all records. Is there a general query for selecting all records, or is there a way to query a layer to return field names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WFS service in the link you provided is not enabled but WMS is enabled, to enable the WFS add below line into your web section in map file:  `"wfs_enable_request" "*"` so it should appear as follow:

```
WEB 
    IMAGEPATH "/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/" 
    IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
    METADATA
           "wms_enable_request" "*"
            "wfs_enable_request" "*"
    END
  END
```

Now to get the columns for layer **parcels**, use below link:

http://qpublic5.qpublic.net/cgi-bin/mapserv56?map=/qpub1/maps/ky/mason/parcel3.map&SERVICE=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeNames=**parcels**

for detailed information about other WFS, check below link:  http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#describefeaturetype

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't believe I have access to or can make changes to the map file. But you say WMS is enabled? How would I structure the url to view the WMS and is it possible to query all features from the WMS?

Comment: Your WMS is enabled as I can get the capabilities & can see the layers as below link:  http://qpublic5.qpublic.net/cgi-bin/mapserv56?map=/qpub1/maps/ky/mason/parcel3.map&SERVICE=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: It does appear that another layer, qparcels, is queryable, but it only seems to return a feature number, when i load the WMS into a desktop GIS

Comment: You can query feature using WMS based on coordinates (x & y) to get the map image but if you need to query an attribute and return data, then you need to enable WFS. check this [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80948/what-are-the-differences-between-wms-wfs-wcs-wps) to get clear image regarding the WMS & WFS.

Comment: I think I generally understand but got a little confused because I'm used to working with esri map services which can allow querying of features. And as I mentioned, it does look like one of the layers in this WMS, qparcels, allows queries.

Answer (score 1):

Per your updated question, to request a schema of the feature attributes you may use desribeFeatureType method.

http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/179

Here is a similar Q/A:

[How to get column names of layer (WMS) using OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33674/how-to-get-column-names-of-layer-wms-using-openlayers)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't even know if WFS is enabled, this is the url for the layer: http://qpublic5.qpublic.net/cgi-bin/mapserv56?map=/qpub1/maps/ky/mason/parcel3.map&mode=map&layer=parcels